# Alternatives to blade templating

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and I'm already sick of the project I'm working on. the most annoying thing so far was blade templates. Are there any alternatives that I could use?

Comment: In Laravel, you can use native PHP in the views. If you don't like blade, don't use it.

Comment: I'm sick of having to ask such questions too. In the end I will stick to blade. I think I have fixed the problem. Laravel documentation was not clear enough. some sites on the web tell you to do it differently, probably because blade has changed over time. In HAML I would get informative warning if something was not right. So you can see why it's easy to get stuck. So, please pardon me for my frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @yeni said use you can Native PHP :

```
<?php Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')); ?>

<?php Form::close(); ?>
```

But if you don't want to use this also you can use Smarty Templates with blade here is bundle link :

Visit : https://github.com/darkimmortal/Laravel4-SmartyView

Answer (score 3):

You could try Twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/ which I've heard is also compatible with Laravel, but is similar to Blade.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Twig Bridge I created: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-twigbridge

You can use Twig templates, just like Blade templates (with creators/composers, Facades, helpers etc)